# Unexpected token with async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax-error

I have also used the syntax of async function like this:

```
const { triggerScheduler } = require('../service/dayEndScheduler');

class DayEndScheduler {
  triggerScheduler = async () => {
    try {
      return triggerScheduler;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error.message);
    }
  };
}

module.exports.DayEndScheduler = DayEndScheduler;
```

But now all of a sudden I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

I use the node.js version 10.22. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Why are you using a `class` at all here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class fields [are only supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) in Node 12+. Either upgrade your Node, or use a method instead:

```
class DayEndScheduler {
  async triggerScheduler () {
    try {
      return triggerScheduler;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error.message);
    }
  }
}
```

But JavaScript is not Java - there's no need to make a class just to be able to use a function. If there really isn't anything else in the class, it would make much more sense to drop the class entirely:

```
module.exports.DayEndScheduler = () => {
  try {
    return triggerScheduler;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
};
```

(though the `try`/`catch` doesn't make sense either - it will never throw, why not just do `module.exports.triggerScheduler = triggerScheduler`, or something similar?)

Comment: Thanks, updated to the latest version and it worked.